# Rewrite domain name/url with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the following url:

```
mydomain.com/dashboard/index.php?user=john-dow
```

to

```
john-dow.mydomain.com/dashboard/index.php
```

So I want to take the query string value and place it at the beginning of my domain followed by a dot. The goal is to create a customized user url, so it looks very friendly to users. But actually, I don't know how can I do that. Is it possible by .htaccess? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in your `dashboard/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%1.mydomain.com/dashboard/index.php? [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried. It create url as i required like: john-dow.mydomain.com/dashboard/index.php      But it doesn't get the index.php file it shows the server not found.

Comment: It's not a problem with .htaccess. You need to configure server and DNS to use wildcard DNS record.

Comment: Hi, can you suggest me or share any like? how to configure server and DNS? Another thing, can I test it on localhost on my ubuntu operating system? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you suggest me a link where have the complete wild card setting tutorial. Thanks again.

Comment: Try "wildcard DNS" with Google, and your DNS server name or web hosting.