# Htaccess URL rewriting id and name

Tags: .htaccess, web

I have my own website and I want this like stackoverflow have

When you look at the url there is a nice url like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587870/javascript-variable-in-bootstrap-tooltip

When I only enter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587870 it send me to the full url.

This is what I have now: http://www.exmaple.com/projects.php?id=1

How can I make this on my own website?

Comment: Build a `htaccess` with this rewrite, you can use the search function on SO or your favorite search engine  to find more information.

Comment: Have you tried doing any searches around SO and see if you can piece an .htaccess together? This is a pretty common thing and has been solved a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite domain name/url with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187889/rewrite-domain-name-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: @JeremyHarris could you send me a example how to fix this?

Comment: @JeremyHarris that is not what i want, i dont wa sub domain only the /id/name on the back on the URL

Comment: You may look into [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), which allows to map from an id to string.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of database for this, which maps an `id` to its appropriate `slug`. This could be as simple as a text file containing the mappings, e.g.

> 41960970 htaccess-url-rewriting-id-and-name
>   40587870 javascript-variable-in-bootstrap-tooltip

You can then define a [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

```
RewriteMap id2slug txt:/path/to/file.txt
```

and then use it in a rule

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+)$ /questions/$1/${id2slug:$1} [R,L]
```

This rule captures the id from the request and then redirects the client to the same URL with a slug appended.

---

Instead of a text file, you can also use other forms like `dbm`, `dbd`, or even an external program providing the mapping.

Be aware though, that `RewriteMap` is only available in the main server or virtual host configuration.

---

When you don't have access to the main config, you might simulate this with a script doing the redirect, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+)$ /id2slug.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and in the script, retrieve the slug from a database and send back

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$slug = ...;
header('Location: http://www.example.com/questions/' . $id . '/' . $slug);
```

Comment: How can i create a virtual host?

Comment: You can do this only, if you have access to the main config. See [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) and [Apache Virtual Host documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/) for details.

Comment: Well, I dont have access to those 2 files, I'm on shared hosting